# how to get selected value of gridview in textbox using MVC(aspx) .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, sqldatasource

net.
i want to get selected value from gridview into textbox,i have used sqlserever database to display data into gridview.
no other links helpful at ol to me.plz help me.

my aspx gridview of BranchManage.aspx page is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
     GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource_Branch">
     <Columns>
          <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="BranchName" HeaderText="BranchName" ReadOnly="True"
               SortExpression="BranchName" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="CreateDate" HeaderText="CreateDate" ReadOnly="True"
               SortExpression="CreateDate" />
     </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
  <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource_Branch" runat="server" 
       ContextTypeName="jemex.db.JemexDataContext" EntityTypeName="" 
      Select="new (BranchName, CreateDate)" TableName="Branches">
  </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

-----And this is my part of code of LoginController.cs:

```
public ActionResult BranchManage(string submitButton, string branchname)
{
   ViewBag.UserName = Session["username"];
   if (Session["type"].ToString() == "Admin")
   {
       switch (submitButton)
       {
           case "Create Account":
              return (Create_BranchAccount(branchname));
           case "Update Account":
              return (Update_BranchAccount());
           case "Clear":
              return (ClearBranch());
           default:
              return View();
         }
    }
    else
   {
      return View("Login");
   }

}
public ActionResult Create_BranchAccount(string branchname)
{
  //DB.Execute_Qury("INSERT INTO Branches(BranchName,CreateDate,IsDeleted) VALUES (" +
   branchname + "," + System.DateTime.Now + ",False)");
   db1.R_Insert_Branch(branchname, System.DateTime.Now);
   return View("BranchManage");
}
 public ActionResult Update_BranchAccount()
{
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=aaa-pc;Initial Catalog=logicnetclub_jemex;Integrated Security=True");
    string strSQL = "Select * from Branches";
    SqlDataAdapter dt = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    dt.Fill(ds, "UserDetail");
    con.Close();
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
      return View(ViewModel);
}
```

Here at update_BranchAccount ,how can i fetch gridview datasource?

Comment: @dav-i Please dont' blindly remove tags from titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the selected value or cell from Grid View into a session and then re-use it somewhere else in the current page or any other required page. So when the page is requested again the value is shown automatically into the text-box.

**::: Try this Sample Code.. Hope that could solve your problem :::**

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in ViewData.Rows)
 {
      RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)row.FindControl("RowSelector");
      if (rb.Checked)
      {                                            
         string address = Convert.ToString(ViewData.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[column-index].Text);
         Session["addressValue"] = address;                   
         Response.Redirect("AnotherPage.aspx");
     }
 }
```

Then at update_BranchAccount, you can access the textbox value using-

> textbox1.text = Session["addressValue"];

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of one selected cell, you can use the `CellClick` event of `gridview`:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really use Model in MVC. Mixed up state-full webform code and Controller will confuse you.

The controller don't know any thing about View(aspx) So You need to parse FormCollection as Model into Action.

```
public ActionResult BranchManage(string branchname, FormCollection formData){
 //.. now debug or test what formData really look like
```

You could change FormCollection to any user-defined type ( the Model)

learn how to parse the Model between controller and view [Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4).